# How to avoid rendering of same node in two different view blocks on same page ?

Tags: 7, views

One of my page shows two different view blocks. Suppose View-block-1 and view-block-2.
Both renders and display nodes from same content type, say products. Node display Limit is set to 1 in both view and ordered by random.

**Products:**

Product 1

Product 2

**Case 1**

View-block-1  |   View-block-2

Product 1     |  Product 2

**Case 2**

View-block-1  |   View-block-2

Product 1    |    Product 1

Problem is that (case 2) sometimes both block shows same node since ordering is set to random.

Is there any way to ensure that both view do not show same node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Views exclude previous module.Then your views filter criteria will have a option like this

Views: Views Exclude Previous (<> Exclude nodes that where loaded in any node based view.)

This will restrict the same content to be displayed in page more than one time.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I saw if there is any option to it, but I think there is some module available 'views exclude previous'. I need to install it first. I'll make a try :)

Comment: Well, Yes. Thank You so much. This worked. But I installed Views exclude previous module prior to use that filter. Please update your post so that I can accept it. :)